# Textbooks, lecture notes, and articles from arXiv for undergraduate students

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, education, big-list, book-recommendation

I have found some interesting textbooks and articles on [**arXiv**](http://arxiv.org), such as the following one, that are *accessible to an undergraduate student*:

> [*Course of linear algebra and multidimensional geometry*](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405323), by
>   Ruslan Sharipov.

My experience makes me believe that in arXiv there may be not only research papers, but also *plenty* of freely available interesting textbooks, lecture notes, and articles that can

- give insightful explanations of topics that are commonly found in an undergraduate degree program;
- but also enrich and broaden the mathematical culture of an *undergraduate* student.

Could you point out some good examples of such material?

Comment: [A geometric approach to differential forms](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306194)

Comment: I found that [Ted Shifrin's textbook](http://math.uga.edu/~shifrin/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf) on differential geometry is wonderfully approachable, certainly to an undergraduate coming out of multivariable calculus

Comment: @Zircht Sorry, I've downloaded the source and tried to open without success. Any hints?

Comment: That's odd, I thought you'd find the pdf, but it's not there. Anyway, you can see it [here](http://www.math.boun.edu.tr/instructors/ozturk/eskiders/fall04math488/bachman.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

While this looks like a self-publicity, but I made this lecture notes on [Bernoulli Polynomials and their applications](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.7560) available on the arXiv. I hope you will find them interesting. They are intended to build every thing from scratch.

Comment: $+1$: Thank you very much for pointing this out, Professor, it really seems interesting. By the way, I see that your interests include analysis. Do you happen to have some lecture notes in undergrad real analysis and advanced calculus?

Answer (score 2):

There is a book ['Category Theory for Scientists'](http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.6946) by David Spivak. I have myself not used it so can not comment on quality though.

Answer (score 2):

For people interested in Lie Algebras and Representation theory, Brian Hall's notes on the topic are available on [arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0005032).

Comment: I've just skimmed through them. I have to say thay they seem really good. Thank you.

Comment: infact, [this](http://www.amazon.com/Lie-Groups-Algebras-Representations-Introduction/dp/0387401229/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1418471871&sr=8-1&keywords=lie+groups+and+lie+algebras+and+representation+theory&pebp=1418471868276) textbook grew out of those notes.

Answer (score 1):

I found this one a while ago:

**Euclidean plane and its relatives;**
a minimalist introduction

*Anton Petrunin*

https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.1630

btw...

Here is a "hack" you can do to look for books on arxiv. Do an advanced search for "these lecture notes" OR "this book" in the *abstract*. Show 200 results per page. Use your browser search now for "these lecture notes" and then for "this book" ont he book. arxiv's search can do exact match for author name, but not for text in the abstract, it seems. That is why the second step is needed with your browser search.